# Can react-native load a js file remotely?

Tags: react-native

In Facebook's official example, it says

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

/**
* Loading JavaScript code - uncomment the one you want.
*
* OPTION 1
* Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
*
* $ npm start
*
* To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer
* (you can get this by typing `ifconfig` into the terminal and selecting the
* `inet` value under `en0:`) and make sure your computer and iOS device are
* on the same Wi-Fi network.
*/

jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```

My question is can I use a js file remotely, e.g., "http://www.example.com/index.ios.bundle"?

I got the error `The requested URL /index.ios.bundle was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, react-native can load a js file remotely.

You should upload your bundled js file to your server and change the `jsCodeLocation` variable.

Comment: would apple approve the app? I am not sure if the would like that

Comment: @Jonathan My app using react-native just pass the apple's review.

Comment: with bundled js being fetched remotely? If they allow that, that would be really cool

Comment: Can U please help with how u did it? How your server serve the `React-Native` files? I mean to .bundle files..